# Geometrical Rotation and Rotation operator relation and ambiguity

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, rotation, geometry, convection

In Cohen-Tannoudji's it is said (vol.1 page 694):

$|\psi \rangle$ is the state of the system before the rotation.

$|\psi ' \rangle$ is the state of the system after the rotation.

$|\psi ' \rangle= R |\psi  \rangle$  in the bracket notation.

Geometrically: $\psi '(\vec r)=\psi (\mathcal{R}^{-1} \vec r)$

Also : $\mathcal{R}$ (geometrical rotation) $\rightarrow R$ (operator)

This is the part I don't fully understand, the notation change and the commentary:

***The relation $\psi '(\vec r)=\psi (\mathcal{R}^{-1} \vec r)$ characterizes it's action in the {$|\vec r\rangle$} representation:
$\langle \vec r|R| \psi \rangle=\langle \mathcal{R}^{-1} \vec r| \psi\rangle$,
where $|\mathcal{R}^{-1} \vec r| \psi\rangle$ is the basis ket of this representation determined by the components of the vector $\mathcal{R}^{-1} \vec r$.***

I have the following questions for the commentary in bolt:

1. What it is meant with "chracterizes it's action in the..."
2. Why here: $\langle \vec r|R| \psi \rangle=\langle \mathcal{R}^{-1} \vec r| \psi\rangle$, we replaced the operator with it's geometrical analogon, instead with the complex conjugate $ R^\dagger$ ?
3. " where $|\mathcal{R}^{-1} \vec r| \psi\rangle$ is the basis ket of this representation determined by the components of the vector $\mathcal{R}^{-1} \vec r$ ". What it is meant with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's be a bit more explicit about what the objects here are:

$\vec r\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a position vector. $\mathcal{R}\in\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is the usual representation of a rotation as a 3d matrix, and hence $\mathcal{R}\vec r\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a rotated position vector.

$R\in O(\mathcal{H})$ is an operator on our Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ ($O(\mathcal{H})$ is just notation for the space of linear operators on $\mathcal{H}$) and so for any state vector $\lvert \psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$, $R\lvert \psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$ is the state vector we get by applying a rotation to a state vector.

There is a [unitary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_representation) map $\rho : \mathrm{SO}(3)\to O(\mathcal{H}), \mathcal{R}\mapsto \rho(\mathcal{R})$ that maps every rotation $\mathcal{R}$ to its representation $\rho(\mathcal{R})\in O(\mathcal{H})$ on the space of states. This map fulfills $\rho(\mathcal{R}^{-1}) = \rho(\mathcal{R})^\dagger$. It's a bit confusing to just call the image under this map $R$, so let's call it $\rho(\mathcal{R})$ from now on.

The ket $\lvert \vec r\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$ is the state that corresponds to a particle localized at $\vec r$. The relation that your quote wants to state is
$$ \lvert \mathcal{R}\vec r\rangle = \rho(\mathcal{R})\lvert \vec r\rangle$$
i.e. applying the rotation to the position vector and then finding the state corresponding to it is the same as taking the state corresponding to the position vector and applying the rotation as an operator on the space of states to it. For the wavefunction of a rotated state $\lvert \psi'\rangle = \rho(\mathcal{R})\lvert \psi\rangle$, this means
\begin{align} \psi'(\vec r) & = \langle \vec r\vert \psi'\rangle = \langle \vec r\rvert \rho(\mathcal{R})\lvert\psi\rangle = (\lvert \vec r\rangle,\rho(\mathcal{R}) \lvert \psi\rangle) = (\rho(\mathcal{R})^\dagger\lvert \vec r\rangle, \lvert \psi\rangle) \\ 
& = (\rho(\mathcal{R}^{-1})\lvert \vec r\rangle, \lvert \psi\rangle) = (\lvert \mathcal{R}^{-1}\vec r\rangle,\lvert \psi\rangle) = \langle \mathcal{R}^{-1}\vec r\vert\psi\rangle = \psi(\mathcal{R}^{-1}\vec r),\end{align}
where we've written $\langle a\vert b\rangle = (\lvert a\rangle, \lvert b\rangle)$ in terms of the inner product $(-,-)$ since the bra-ket notation obscures a bit what's going on here.